# Multiple questions in same post

Tags: discussion

From time to time, I stumble upon single post on ESE containing many questions which might be related or not like this one : [Help needed understanding ERC20 smart contract functions and workflow](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24465/help-needed-understanding-erc20-smart-contract-functions-and-workflow) 
In my opinion, as it makes the answer a hard task, I think we need to define a cap of the number of questions per post (a kind of a rule of thumb), if not respected we edit or close the question.
I am discussing this issue, to help both sides : users who answer and who ask, because, it turns out that many times i escape answering, if i see many questions in the same post (if you do the same so they will get no answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach taken in most StackExchange sites is simply to close questions like this.

The potted close reason *Too Broad* contains the text: (emphasis mine)

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough
>   detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct
>   questions at once**. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this
>   question.

Such questions are of little use to future visitors.
They are difficult to find when checking if a question has been asked before.
Answers may possibly only apply to one of the questions in the post.
It is almost impossible to select an answer to accept.
Just one of the questions in the post may actually be a duplicate.

If the questions in the post can be treated as one underlying question, then it should remain open.  However, I don't believe this site should permit multiple questions when other sites don't.

The number of questions per post should be one.

Answer (score 0):

I think if they're all related (i.e., all aspects of one reasonable meta-question), it's reasonable to give a general explanation. That said, that example is a bit much.

Three seems like a good rule of thumb to me, though not an absolute harsh guideline.

EDIT: I now agree with Chenmunka.